# Choosing frontend technology like React or Angular for modernization of Silverlight App with more than 1000 different forms/views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, silverlight

We want to convert our silver light application to some modern web technologies like react or angular or any other suitable because Silverlight's end of life is approaching at the end of this year.

I am looking for the advice to choose the best frontend technology on following requirement parameters

1. Silverlight application has more around 1000 views/forms to be converted to new frame work
2. Silver light application is very fast once its loaded on browser, new choice should at least be near to the performance that we get in Silverlight
3. Is there any tool or technique available, by which some of the code may be reused in that new technology
4. How the choice of front end technology would impact the maintainability of the code? Which one is easy to maintain?
5. What strategy we can use to load the application in chunks on browser instead of loading it at once because it would be of huge size?

   - All in one go
   - On demand loading
   - Privilege based interface loading

I am more inclined towards using Reacjs but i need your help in deciding which javascript framework would be the best fit here Reactjs,AngularJs, Vuejs or any other.

Comment: Perhaps investigate platform.uno as well if it NEEDS to web-based, it's uses the UWP XAML model in the browser (which evolved from Silverlights), so should be able to reuse most of your code and XAML. If it doesn't need to be in a web browser, use UWP XAML directly.

Answer (score 2):

1. 2. 3. 

If you do care about the effort needed to change you should consider first moving to **OpenSilver** (webassembly silverlight replacement) or **WPF** with maybe clickonce for deployment. That way you can start with something similar to today with better performance.

We did the switch to *WPF* and *ClickOnce*  a couple of years ago with maybe 50+ complex forms and it was mostly search and replace to change some xaml namespaces so it should be possible to do in days. And our end users (and even their IT departments have been quite happy)

Once switches you can start migrating pages to html based technology one by one by using the webview2 or maybe even blazorview and hosting the page within the application.

4. Maintainability will mostly affected by how you use it and the structure you make. You will find people arguing for all of the different technologies and saying their favorite is the best, so better to try them out in small scale and se what fit the team.
5. 

If you go with clickonce consider using a CDN with good compression support and (you can also use optional delayed components if it is a big issue).
You might want to consider not to make everything a single SPA unless you have good reasons to do so but have many different pages instead that will make it easier to have fast startup.

Answer (score 0):

3. UWP if a Windows desktop front-end would satisfy requirements. Blazor if it has to be Web-based.
4. Answer is probably mainly opinion-based. More to do with structure of the code than the tech imo.
5. Just load the content when it is needed.